# Mysql cannot be started after updating os x mavericks

Tags: mysql, osx-mavericks

My mysql was running good when my os x is 10.8.5, and I update os x mavericks today, after finishing updating, I run the command "mysql -uroot -pmypwd mydatabase" and I cannot enter mysql anymore.

zsh: command not found: mysql

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `mysql` binary no longer is on your PATH.

If you use brew you should repair the brew installation using `brew update` and if it still do not work use `brew doctor` to find the problem.

If you installed it in some other way you need to add mysql to the PATH environment variable again.

Comment: I fixed this problem by adding a soft link:
ln -sf /usr/local/mysql-ur-version /usr/local/mysql 
and run the command "sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start"

Answer (score 1):

Update your PATH, in terminal type:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

You can test if this will work by entering the full executable path:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

See [PATH details](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) and [MySQL OSX installation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/osx-installation.html)  for additional information.

Comment: Worked.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`brew update` does no modify your `PATH`, so probably link to mysql binary is missing.

Check with:

```
echo $PATH | grep --color /usr/local/bin
```

and try to fix with:

```
brew unlink mysql && brew link mysql
```